# How is the output for the following cpp program justified

Tags: c++, arrays, output, character

```
char a[4];
cin >> a;
char b[3];
cin >> b;
cout << a << "\n";
cout << b;
```

input: india 
        lockdown
Gives me output :  kdown
                    lockdown

while hard coding the char array like

```
char a[]= "india"
char b[]= "winner"
cout << a <<" " << b;
```

gives me the expected result
can you please explain the reason of the unexpected results....
Thanks

Comment: [Using cin for char array](//stackoverflow.com/a/29479225)

Comment: why do you expect that storing a 5 characters long string in an array of 4 characters will work? (even without the null-terminator)

Comment: Let me give you a piece of advice, *don't use character arrays in the first place*. Use `std::string` which is dynamically allocated and also resizes to fit in with the input.

Comment: @idclev463035818  understood the point
max of size-1 character needs to be entered
so that it becomes null terminated and we get the desired o/p Thanks

Answer (score 6):

What you observe is a book example of buffer overflow. User input doesn't fit the buffer, and you get garbage written into some other variables on the stack. C++ standard says this is UB (undefined behavior), so many things may happen.

In your second example, the size of the arrays is chosen automatically to fit the strings (including null-character terminators).

Comment: Thanks now i understand that only when in char[4] i can give a input of 3 size so that i haave it null terminated automatically and then i get a correct (desired) output